# Traverse and find elements in XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to search through an XML file and find a text entry then find its parent and then within that selector find the value of another selector within it.  For whatever reason I am failing here.  Here is some dummy data.

```
<Container>
    <Address></Address>
    <DisplayName>This is the text we are looking for</DisplayName>
    <Phone>888-888-8888</Phone>
    <UrlName>Really want this text</UrlName>
</Container>
<Container>
    <Address></Address>
    <DisplayName>This is the text we dont want</DisplayName>
    <Phone>888-888-8888</Phone>
    <UrlName>Not Interested</UrlName>
</Container>
```

I am using an ajax call to an API and it looks something like this.

```
// h1 = This is the text we are looking for
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1").textContent;

$.ajax({

    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.example.com/api",
    dataType: "xml",

    success: function(xml){
        var container = $(xml).find('Container').find('DisplayName');
        var urlName = $(container).find(h1).closest('Container').find('UrlName').text();
        console.log(urlName);
    },

    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }

});
```

So in our HTML we can grab the h1 on the page and we know the h1 equals the DisplayName in the API but the field I need is the UrlName.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, just needed to walk away for a bit and come back.  I will leave answer for anyone in the future.  Hope this helps.

```
// h1 = This is the text we are looking for
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1").textContent;
// my h1 value looked like this <h1>     This is the text we are looking for</h1>
// this is the bane of my first problem
h1 = h1.trim();

$.ajax({

type: "GET",
url: "http://www.example.com/api",
dataType: "xml",

success: function(xml){
    //I also found out I needed to escape the contains function to add my dynamic variable
    var container = $(xml).find('Container').find("DisplayName:contains('"+ h1 +"')";
    var urlName = $(container).closest('Container').find('UrlName').text();
    console.log(urlName);
},

error: function() {
    console.log("error");
}
```

});